# Anyone know of a good open source spam checker in java or c#?

Tags: c#, java, open-source, spam-prevention

I'm creating a website where users can write articles and comment on the articles.  I want to automatically check to see if a new article or comment is spam.

What are good libraries for doing this?

I looked at bayesian classifier libraries, but it seems that I would have to gather a large amount of samples and classify them all as spam or not spam myself...

I'm looking for something that can hopefully just tell me right out of the box.

UPDATE: Maybe if something like this doesn't exist, does anyone know of a download of a large amount of classifications of spam vs not spam that can be fed into a bayesian classifier?

Comment: Bayesian classifier libraries will catch on to spam/ham distinction quicker than you think. What is your target audience?

Comment: I understand. But I'm guessing the manual moderation will get small very quickly. Add in a bit of crowd sourcing (get your users to flag spam for you) and you will be set up.

Comment: @daren I'll give them a try.  You'd think that with spam such a common problem there would be something that just works out of the box by now...

Comment: one persons spam could be another persons ham. That is why i asked for the target audience.

Comment: @daren oh, the target audience is just the general public, the articles could be about anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [Akismet .NET 2.0 Api](http://www.codeplex.com/AkismetApi) on CodePlex.

Here's an example from the CodePlex page:

```
// Verify key
Akismet api = new Akismet("key", "http://url.com", "Test/1.0");
if (!api.VerifyKey()) throw new Exception("Key could not be verified.");

// Create comment object for testing
AkismetComment comment = new AkismetComment();
comment.Blog = "http://joel.net";
comment.UserIp = "147.202.45.202";
comment.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)";
comment.CommentContent = "<a href=\"http://someone.finderinn.com\">find someone</a>";
comment.CommentType = "comment";
comment.CommentAuthor = "someone";
comment.CommentAuthorEmail = "backthismailtojerry@fastmail.fm";
comment.CommentAuthorUrl = "http://someone.finderrin.com";

// Test comment against akismet's service
bool isSpam = api.COmmentCheck(comment);
```

Akismet rocks.

-Charles

Answer (score 0):

Mollom isn't free, but it provides an API too.

http://mollom.com/features

http://mollom.com/pricing